# Getting calendar events in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android

I am  new to the android development. I am working on calender application where i need to add/delete and get all events in between the date range. I have add and delete the events successufully but problem is when i am getting the calender events in between the date range. I  am getting the calender events but when i go to SPlanner i can see those events are not added in the calender as i have already deleted them. I do not know from where i am getting those events.Please suggest. Here is the code i have written to get the calender events:-

```
public void onGetEvent (final String fullCallbackName, String title,String startDate,String endDate) throws JSONException
    {
            try
            {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                final ArrayList<JSONObject> calEvents = new ArrayList();
                 if(calEvents.size() !=0)
                 {
                      calEvents.clear();
                 }

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                String selection = "((dtstart >= "+(dateFormat.parse(startDate).getTime())+") AND (dtend <= "+(dateFormat.parse(endDate).getTime())+"))";

                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase() + "events"),
                       (new String[] { "_id", "title", "dtstart","dtend","eventLocation","description"}), selection, null, null);
                Log.e("cursor.getCount before:","callbackFuncName:" +  cursor.getCount());
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {                       
                     String _id = cursor.getString(0);
                     String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
                        Log.e("cursor.getCount before:","callbackFuncName:" +  displayName);


                     String[] separated = displayName.split(":");
                     if(separated[0]!= null && title.equals(separated[0]))
                    {
                        JSONObject dictionary =  new JSONObject();

                        String dstart = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(2))));//cursor.getString(2);    
                        String dEnd = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));//cursor.getString(3);  
                        String eventlocation = cursor.getString(4);   
                        String description = cursor.getString(5); 
                        dictionary.put("identifier", _id);
                        dictionary.put("title", displayName);
                        dictionary.put("startDate", dstart);
                        dictionary.put("endDate", dEnd);
                        dictionary.put("venue", eventlocation);
                        dictionary.put("notes", description);
                        calEvents.add(dictionary);


                    }
                }

                if(fullCallbackName != null && !fullCallbackName.equals(""))
                {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {

                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+fullCallbackName+" ("+calEvents+")") ; 
                        }
                    });
                }


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            Log.e("string", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

code for getting the calender DB is:-

```
private String getCalendarUriBase() {
        String calendarUriBase = null;
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // eat
        }

        if (cursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
        } else {
            calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
            try {
                cursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // eat
            }

            if (cursor != null) {
                calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
            }

        }
        Log.d("Sandeep",
                calendarUriBase);
       // managedCursor.close();
        return calendarUriBase;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your query you will see deleted events because they are still in the database (for being able to sync the deletion whenever the next sync is due). That's what the [DELETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns.html#DELETED) column is for.

To find all events between a start and end date use the [Instances](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html) class of the CalendarContract API as in the code below. This code returns only visible events!

I've written a [blog post about the CalendarContract content provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/) detailing this and other stuff.

```
   long begin = // starting time in milliseconds; for you probably cursor.getLong(2)
   long end = // ending time in milliseconds; cursor.getLong(3)
   String[] proj = 
         new String[]{
               Instances._ID, 
               Instances.TITLE,
               Instances.BEGIN,
               Instances.END,
               Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
               Instances.DESCRIPTION,
               Instances.EVENT_ID};
   Cursor cursor = 
         Instances.query(getContentResolver(), proj, begin, end);
   if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      // do your JSON thing
   }
```